# Vuetify: Horizontally align v-select and v-btn components

Tags: vuetify.js

How can I horizontally align the *v-select* with the *v-btn*?

[image]

Here is the code (can be tested in the Playground link below):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-btn variant="outlined">Test</v-btn>
      <v-select
        v-model="selected"
        class="d-inline-flex"
        variant="outlined"
        density="compact"
        :items="['Item1', 'Item2']"
        hide-details
      ></v-select>
      <v-btn variant="outlined">Test</v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const selected = ref('Item1')
</script>
```

[Playground link (contains code)](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest fix is to adjust vertical alignment:

```html
<v-select
  class="flex-grow-0"
  style="vertical-align: middle;"
  ...
```

[playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

---

Might be easier to do it through the container though:

```html
<v-container class="d-flex align-center">
  ...
  <v-select
    class="flex-grow-0"
    ...
```

[playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)